# Free tool to automaticaly document XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, documentation-generation

When you create XML for some communication or as a configuration file, you will probably want to explain to others how this file works. What tag is used for what.

First, you will create XSD, where you will define how to create and use XML. And there are the `annotation` and `documentation` tags to explain it better.
But, is there a tool how to convert XSD into documentation that is more readable to common users? For example in set od `html` files or in `tex` or `pdf` file.

If it have relationship images, that would be even better, but this is not a must.

Comment: This tool can do that, but it is not free. https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xml_schema_diagram_editor.html

Answer (score 1):

This could be the one solution I found out.

Using this xsl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xs3p, XSD can be converted into the html.
You only need to compile XSD and XSL. Here is the example in python:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('MY_XML_SCHEMA.xsd')
xslt = ET.parse('xs3p.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
with open('MY_XML_SCHEMA.html', 'w') as html:
    html.write(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```